# How would I use js to convert a decimal to number to a hex string?

Tags: javascript, hex, decimal

Decimal input: **76561198291043943**
Hex output: **110000113b74660**
Hex expected output: **110000113b74667**

For some reason, when I use the following snippet and execute it, the expected result does not occur, but when I use https://www.binaryhexconverter.com/decimal-to-hex-converter to convert a decimal number to a hex string, I get the expected output.

```js
console.log(Number(76561198291043943).toString(16))
```

Comment: That number has too many digits to fit in the precision of a floating point number.

Comment: If you just enter `76561198291043943` into the JavaScript console, it prints `76561198291043940`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`76561198291043943` is greater than [`Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER).

Use [`BigInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) instead:

```js
console.log(BigInt("76561198291043943").toString(16))
```